# How much expenditure for children

Tags: retirement, children

I've been reading about 4% rule and about saving well and so on. My current savings rate is decent I think. However, we do plan on having a kid in the near future. I am not really sure what our savings rate will be then.

Articles that I read online seem to indicate that kids are really expensive -- they are expensive when they are infants, expensive when they go to college etc.

What is the realistic number for expenditure for kids?

Specific details about my situation:

1. One kid
2. Exclude college costs (I will estimate that to be 250k)
3. Living in Seattle USA
4. Exclude Nanny
5. Include food supplies clothing

Comment: A lot of it depends on where you live but this is a good starting point: https://www.thebump.com/a/advice-for-saving-up-for-a-baby As for education cost, you could look into starting a 529 plan, if you're in the US.

Comment: This is mostly opinion based because it depends on the location and your own views on what is necessary for a child (a baby can grow up just fine without 80% of the things that are advertised everywhere). See [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125432/how-much-should-we-have-save-before-having-a-child-baby-planning-a-couple-years) as well (closed as opinion based).

Comment: I think this question can be improved if OP can add: a) a Geographic location, b) what child expenses are planned (for example are you saving/paying for college or having your adult child pay their own way, saving for a first car?, saving for a grand wedding when the child is older?), c) just the one kid or two or three or more? plans change but what's your target (also twins happen). Narrow this down to YOUR situation and preferences and the community can provide a more actionable answer.

Comment: @Freiheit - Some of the expenses that that you listed are not considered as part of  the cost of raising a child (college, wedding).  An adult child is an adult.  Raising means from birth until 18.

Answer (score 1):

Periodically, there's a news article (Time Magazine, etc.) detailing  how much it costs a middle income family in the USA to raise a child to age 18.  I don't know the latest numbers but the last time I read one, it was about an average cost of  $250k.   Of course, location matters.  It's more expensive in the northeast and on the west coast than in the south and in rural areas.

For more accurate numbers, go to the US Department of Agriculture web site. They make the annual calculation and supposedly, there is an interactive tool there for inputting specific details.

Comment: When mine was born, I started saving for college. College savings alone was close to $250K. The question is too broad, and being voted to close as opinion based, if only for the fact that there's a range of cost that's very broad. Child care alone can range from $0 with a stay at home parent/grandparent to $50K/yr for a nanny.

Comment: These estimates are based on up to age 18 since that is adulthood.  College is for parents who care ;->)